# get nested list out of list after normalizing it

Tags: python-3.x

I have to perform one function on my nested list i.e to normalize it but unfortunately I'm not getting the original nested list.

I tried using list of list

```
x = [[7.334, 2.234234, 3.3454], [4.1232, 8.345], [2.435, 4.435, 6.453]]
m = list(map(max, zip(*x)))
n = list(map(min, zip(*x)))

print(m)
print(n)


def get_normalize_value(s):
    t = list(zip(m, n))
    c = []
    for k in t:
        c.append(list(k))
    for i in c:
        k, h = i
        v = (s-h)/(k-h)
        return round(v, 2)


def get():
    another_list = [[get_normalize_value(j)] for i in x for j in i]
    return another_list


print(get())
```

so what I get after this was

> [[1.0], [-0.04], [0.19], [0.34], [1.21], [0.0], [0.41], [0.82]]

but I want it is nested as it was

> [[1.0, -0.04, 0.19],[ 0.34, 1.21],[0.0, 0.41, 0.82]]

Answer (score 0):

I modified your `get` function to get this output:

```
def get():
    result = []
    for i in x:
        result.append([get_normalize_value(j) for j in i])
    return result
```

Output:

> [[1.0, -0.04, 0.19], [0.34, 1.21], [0.0, 0.41, 0.82]]